# Problem with replacing placeholders in xml configured in contextConfigLocation param

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

When I put placeholder in web.xml then it is correctly replaced by value defined in catalina.properties or -D param from vm options. But don't work when i put placeholder into xml which is loaded by ContextLoaderListener.

web.xml snippet:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        ${placeholder}, <!-- WORKS -->
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml <!-- DON'T WORK, WHEN PLACEHOLDER IS DEFINED INSIDE XML -->
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Xml defined in contextConfigLocation is loaded by spring and it is required to define bean from class org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. Properties file can be empty. Values will be loaded from catalina.properties or vm options.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:example.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```